# Accidental Overrides when trying to provide operators for a type in a context

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, extension-methods

Following the design paradigm in kmath with algebraic contexts, I am trying to build a context interface for encoding abstract vector space types: where one scalar type fulfills the `Field` contract and has corresponding operators defined, and the other vector type fulfills the `Group` contract and has its operators correspondingly defined.

I tried inheriting from both `Field<FieldType>` and `Group<GroupType>`, but this doesn't work. So next I tried building my own interface, building on `Ring`, `FieldOps` and `NumericAlgebra` from kmath:

```
public interface Equality<T> {
    public infix fun T.eq(other: Any?): Boolean
}

public interface FieldContext<CoefficientT> :
    Ring<CoefficientT>, FieldOps<CoefficientT>, NumericAlgebra<CoefficientT>, Equality<CoefficientT>

public interface VectorSpaceContext<FieldT, VectorT> : FieldContext<FieldT> {
    // A module has addition, subtraction, unit, scalar multiplication

    public val origin : VectorT

    public fun vectorAdd(left: VectorT, right: VectorT): VectorT

    public fun vectorNegate(v: VectorT): VectorT = vectorSubtract(origin, v)
    public fun vectorSubtract(left: VectorT, right: VectorT): VectorT = vectorAdd(left, vectorNegate(right))

    public fun vectorScale(scalar: FieldT, vector: VectorT): VectorT

    // Type extension operators to enable all these within a context block
    public operator fun VectorT.unaryPlus(): VectorT = this@unaryPlus
    public operator fun VectorT.unaryMinus(): VectorT = vectorNegate(this@unaryMinus)
    public operator fun VectorT.plus(other: VectorT): VectorT = vectorAdd(this@plus, other)
    public operator fun VectorT.minus(other: VectorT): VectorT = vectorSubtract(this@minus, other)
    public operator fun FieldT.times(other: VectorT): VectorT = vectorScale(this@times, other)
    public operator fun VectorT.times(other: FieldT): VectorT = vectorScale(other, this@times)
}
```

But even after renaming `add(left: VectorT, right: VectorT)` to `vectorAdd` et.c. I am getting **Accidental override** compiler errors for all my extension operators. The errors look like this:

```
e: file:///[...path...]/Chain.kt:61:1 Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (minus(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;):
    fun CoefficientT.minus(arg: CoefficientT): CoefficientT defined in [package].ChainContext
    fun Any?.minus(other: Any?): Any? defined in [package].ChainContext
```

Now, I don't understand where the `fun Any?.minus(other: Any?): Any?` comes from. I don't see anything like it in my code, and the kmath definitions for the interfaces I inherit from also are specific to that particular type. And even if I could give a `@JvmName` annotation to rename them in the JVM bytecode, I worry about losing their use as their corresponding operator symbols.

The error refers to `ChainContext`, which is a specific implementation of the `VectorSpaceContext` interface:

```
public class ChainContext<VertexT, CoefficientT>(
    vertexComparator: Comparator<VertexT>,
    public val coefficientContext: FieldContext<CoefficientT>,
) :
    VectorSpaceContext<CoefficientT, Chain<VertexT, CoefficientT>>,
    FieldContext<CoefficientT> by coefficientContext,
    SimplexContext<VertexT>(vertexComparator) {
    override val origin: Chain<VertexT, CoefficientT> = [...]
    override fun vectorScale(scalar: CoefficientT, vector: Chain<VertexT, CoefficientT>): Chain<VertexT, CoefficientT> = [...]
    override fun vectorNegate(v: Chain<VertexT, CoefficientT>): Chain<VertexT, CoefficientT> = [...]
    override fun vectorAdd(left: Chain<VertexT, CoefficientT>,right: Chain<VertexT, CoefficientT>): Chain<VertexT, CoefficientT> = [...]

    [... more stuff ...]
}
```

Comment: Try commenting out your minus function and then typing `Any().minus(Any())` inside a function somewhere in your code and then control+click the “minus” to have the IDE jump to the function it’s calling.